# gradle eclipse always says my webapp:eclipse is UP-TO-DATE

Tags: gradle

I am trying to get the source refs in the .classpath file so I remove my webapp/.classpath, webapp/.project and webapp/.settings stuff but gradle keeps printing this every time...

```
:eclipseClasspath
:eclipseJdt
:eclipseProject
:eclipse
:master:eclipseClasspath
:master:eclipseJdt
:master:eclipseProject
:master:eclipse
:webapp:eclipse UP-TO-DATE
```

No, it's clearly not up to date since it has no .classpath file!!!!  grrrrrrr, My webapp dependencies are defined like so...(**where master project uses ivy to define lots of dependencies**)

```
    dependencies {
        compile project(':master')

        compile fileTree(dir: '../webapp/play-1.2.5/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
                                                                                    //, excludes: ['*log4j*','slf4j*'])
        compile fileTree(dir: '../webapp/play-1.2.5/framework', include: 'play-*.jar')
    }
```

My master dependencies are like so

```
 project(':master') {
    project.ext.genLibDir = file('../webapp/lib')
    project.ext.fixedLibDir = file('libother')

    configurations {
        compile.exclude module: 'commons'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework'
    all*.exclude module: 'log4j'
    all*.exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    all*.exclude module: 'junit'
    all*.exclude module: 'antlr'
    all*.exclude module: 'snakeyaml'
    }

    dependencies {
            compile group: 'org.acegisecurity',  name: 'acegi-security',          version: '1.0.7'

            //compile group: 'org.hibernate',    name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.1.4.Final'
            //compile group: 'org.slf4j',          name: 'slf4j-api',               version: '1.6.6'
            compile 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.6.6'
            compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.6'
            compile 'com.ning:async-http-client:1.7.6'
            //ERASE this one as this client seems to suck usability-wise!!!
            compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:4.0-beta3'

            compile group: 'ch.qos.logback',     name: 'logback-core',            version: '1.0.6'
            compile group: 'ch.qos.logback',     name: 'logback-classic',         version: '1.0.6'
            //compile group: 'joda-time',         name: 'joda-time',               version: '2.1'
            compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl',    version: '1.9.8'
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?  Why will it not generate my .classpath file???

I am running "gradle eclipse"

turning on debug results in these logs for webapp:eclipse

```
07:34:13.822 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :webapp:eclipse
07:34:13.822 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':webapp:eclipse'
07:34:13.823 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter] Skipping task ':webapp:eclipse' as it has no actions.
07:34:13.823 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':webapp:eclipse'
07:34:13.823 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :webapp:eclipse UP-TO-DATE
```

Another section of my build file I should mention is I apply the eclipse plugin to all projects like so

```
 allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

project structure is simple

```
SDI
   master
   webapp
```

In my opinion, the logging is not good enough and is therefore a bug itself as anything that is up to date should really tell you why so I could continue.  Anyway to turn on more logging?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Maybe show your project structure too?